# How to merge output of a cascading job to a specific size

Tags: hadoop, cascading

I have a cascading job that outputs 30 25MB files. Is there anyway I can reduce it to 256 mb files each. I tried -Dmapreduce.job.reduces=1. It does not seem to wrok. ANy guidance would be helpful

Comment: Would concatenation afterwards be OK, or do you want do get it done directly? Also, can you describe the input files (number and size) and corresponding mappers. -- As an inefficient but possibly effective trick: Try putting a sort at the end and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried setting the number of reducers for some of the pipes to 1. Even then this is happening. In map reduce it is a simple seting, but in Cascading it seems a bit complicated

Comment: You have mentioned "-Dmapreduce.job.reduces", is that a typo here or in your config ? It should be -Dmapreduce.job.reducers instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Total memory = 30*25 = 750 ,
>
> required output files = 750/256 = 3 ,

You can add one more map-reduce task in your job.On final output pipe put group by or unique or any operation for which you can set number of reducers and set number of reducers as 3 or 4 so you will get number of output files as number of reducers.